# Unable to define a list of variable type and size using template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a list as a private member of a class that has two template arguments: `type` for the data type of the list elements and `size` for the number of elements in the list. To this end, I want to use the list's fill constructor using my two template arguments. Here is my attempt:

```
#include <list>

template <typename type, unsigned int size>
class my_class {

   private:
      std::list<type> my_queue(size, 0);

   // More code here...

};
```

My approach seems to follow the information and example provided [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/); but when I compile this, I get the following error.

```
error: 'size' is not a type
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

It seems as though it recognizes the declaration of the list by its default constructor instead of the fill constructor. Can anyone help me solve this?

Thank you!

**Edit:** here is my revised source with more detail. I am now having trouble with the public method. *Note:* this is my class's header file.

```
#include <list>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class my_class {

   private:

      std::list<T> my_queue;

   public:

      // Constructor
      my_class() : my_queue(N, 0) { }

      // Method
      T some_function(T some_input);
      // The source for this function exists in another file.

};
```

**Edit 2:** Final implementation... thank you, @billz!

```
#include <list>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class my_class {

   private:

      std::list<T> my_queue;

   public:

      // Constructor
      my_class() : my_queue(N, 0) { }

      // Method
      T some_function(T some_input){
         // Code here, which accesses my_queue
      }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could only initialize member variable in constructor before C++11, better use uppercase character as template argument:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class my_class {
   public:
    my_class() : my_queue(N, 0) { }

   private:
      std::list<T> my_queue;

   // More code here...

};
```

Edit:

T some_function(T some_input); C++ only supports inclusive-module, you need to define `some_function` in the same file as my_class is declared.

Comment: This seems to work, although I have a public method which has an input argument and return type that matches `T`. When I compile my main program that calls this method, it says claims an "undefined reference" to that method. (Please see the original post, I've edited the sample code to show this method.) Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you define that function inside my_class or separated it somewhere else?

Comment: you can't use `CQ() ` as name, it must be class name as constructor name

Comment: Well, it _is_ inside `my_class`; however, the prototype and implementation are separated into a header and source file, respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I have `CQ` as the class name in my actual project -- I changed the name for this example to be more clear. As for the template not being like a normal class... do you mean that I can't split up the method prototype and implementation between files? Or can I not have that method altogether? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `can't split up the method prototype and implementation between files`, that's it

Comment: I just ditched the header file, added in `#include "my_class.cpp"` to the top of my main program, and added my_class.cpp as an argument to g++. Works great now! Thank you!

Comment: That's but, better include it in the bottom of `my_class.hpp` though